# Maven dependency generation

Tags: maven

Is there a plugin available for maven which i can use to generate all the dependencies of a project ? For example I have a server folder which contains folders like below

```
-server
--test1
--test2
--test3
```

when i run a particular comand from server folder it should generate all the dependency info in the target folder of server. I know if I use **dependency:analyze-report** it will generate in all the folders target, but I want then all together in the top folder. Please let me know if there is any way.

Comment: Have you tried: `mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file`

Comment: its still generating inside the specific folders